# DATEADD function for Azure database

Tags: c#, sql, sql-server, azure

I am developing a web application that connects to an Azure database. I am trying to use the DATEADD function but I am getting an error.

My code:

```
SqlCommand commandAvg = new SqlCommand("SELECT AVG (" + statDataSelection + ") FROM Buoy3v3 WHERE time >'" + TextBox1_fromDate.Text + "' AND time <'" + TextBox2_toDate.Text + "';", connection);
commandAvg.CommandType = CommandType.Text;

SqlCommand commandAvg1month = new SqlCommand("SELECT AVG (" + statDataSelection + ") FROM Buoy3v3 WHERE time > (DATEADD(month, 1,'" + TextBox1_fromDate.Text + "')) AND time < (DATEADD(month, 1,'" + TextBox2_toDate + "')) ;", connection);
commandAvg1month.CommandType = CommandType.Text;

string Avgresult = commandAvg.ExecuteScalar().ToString();
string Avgresult1month = commandAvg1month.ExecuteScalar().ToString();
```

The Avgresult variable works fine but I am getting an error for the Avgresult1month variable so I assume my problem is with the DATEADD function but I can't figure out what is wrong.

Any help is greatly appreciated.

Comment: What is the error exactly?

Comment: Consider reading the error message.

Comment: It was as simple as not having TextBox2_toDate.Text. Thanks for taking the time to answer.

Comment: In future please post the error

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You coded :

```
SqlCommand commandAvg1month = new SqlCommand("SELECT AVG (" + statDataSelection + ") FROM Buoy3v3 WHERE time > (DATEADD(month, 1,'" + TextBox1_fromDate.Text + "')) AND time < (DATEADD(month, 1,'" + TextBox2_toDate + "')) ;", connection);
commandAvg1month.CommandType = CommandType.Text;
```

Do you think that SQL is clever as that a string is a DateTime ? ;)

Correct `TextBox1_FromDate.Text` and `TextBox2_ToDate` variables in your DateADD function

Answer (score 0):

In theory, you're concatenating a `TextBox` to your string (which will be `System.Web.UI.WebControls.TextBox`, and not the actual value of the `Text` property).

```
TextBox2_toDate.Text << .Text
```

But in practice, you should bind it as a parameter, not concatenate it directly for a number of reasons, including:

- If the date isn't entered in a compliant format ?
- Vulnerabilities to Sql Injection attacks

Also note that `TIME` is a reserved word and needs to be treated by adding brackets, i.e. `[TIME]`